# What should be done in the case of a misunderstood answer actually being correct on out of question clarification?

Tags: discussion

On [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/does-backlash-reduce-the-targeting-number-when-casting-a-spell) question, @DForck42 pointed out that the answer I chased down was actually what he had meant in his answer after I posted and accepted the answer I solicited from another source.  What I did was take my answer and update my question with it, deleted my answer, and updated his answer to be clearer.  Then I accepted his answer.  I just don't know if this was the right thing to do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its pretty much up to you as you were the asker and the accepted answerer. If this solution was adequate to you then it sounds like an excellent solution.

In the future, if your answer was clearer than the other answerer then its ok to leave your answer. If there are two similar answers stating the same thing in different ways then they both certainly have value, accept the clearer (to you) of the two and leave the other one so that people who think differently can still glean value from the answer that is more clear to them.

Comment: Addendum -- Also remember that editing another's answer for clarity, or to add supporting references, is perfectly acceptable on StackExchange.

Comment: Though it doesn't hurt to indicate either in the answer what you updated or in the comments.  (Unless there is a way to find what has changed somewhere?  I can't find a history ala Wikipedia myself but someone may be able to enlighten me!)

Comment: @mirv - if you click on the time stamp next to "edited" you can see a page that will give you a listing of all of the changes that have been made to a post. There is also a "diff" view where you can see the two posts side by side with the changes highlighted.

Comment: @waxeagle Thanks!